# Can't use clear sans font in a latex document [Ubuntu 20.04 LTS]

Tags: fonts, latex, pdflatex, texmaker

I'm trying to create a project report using latex. I started to write it in windows 10, then I moved in ubuntu, but when I try to compile my latex code (I use TeXmaker) it gives me this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `ClearSans.sty' not found.
```

These are the packages I imported in my latex document:

```
% importing font packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% use clear sans font
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}

% define the document language
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% use the package to create a backgrund
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
```

Is there a way I can use clear sans font in a latex document in ubuntu?
Hope the question was clear and thank you for your time!

Comment: If you use vanilla texlive, you can install the package with `tlmgr install clearsans`. If you use the texlive from ubuntu repos, you need to find out which collections contains it